# How to use show Raster Attribute Table in OpenLayers?

Tags: postgis, arcmap, geoserver, openlayers, raster-attribute-table

I have some GeoTIFF files that I am showing on an openLayers map using GeoServer. Now, I wish to access a Build Raster Attribute table on my web application. In other words, if a user clicks on a point on the GeoTIFF raster layer, they should see the corresponding value shown by ArcMAP in Raster Attribute Table. I am new to the GIS.

I am thinking of creating a database with PostGIS, but I don't know how I should map the Raster Attribute Table in the database.